# How to center or align cells in the table if the cell text is in multiple lines?

Tags: tables, align, alignment, center

The code I am using centers horizontally and vertically all cells.

But if the cell text breaks in multiple lines (cells under the Summary column), the left cells are not centred horizontally any more (see figure below).
Also, how to align to right all cells under the Summary, apart from the top cell (row)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!b]
\caption{Summary and comparisons of test methods}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ K{5mm} | K{15mm} | K{15mm} || K{20mm} }
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\#} & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Combination} & \multirow{2}{*}{Summary} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & A & B &  \\ \hline \hline
    1 & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering 1} & A & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    2 & & B &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    3 & \multirow{4}{=}{\centering 2} & A & Note 1. Note 2. \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    4 & & B & See \#3 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    5 & & C & Note 1. Note 2 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    6 & & D & Note 1. Note 2. Note 3. Note 4. \\ \cline{1-4}
    7 & \multirow{4}{=}{\centering 2} & A &  \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    8 & & B & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    9 & & C & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    10 & & D & \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:PWM4legComparison}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell} %<-----
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize} %<-----
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}} %<-----


\begin{document}

\begin{table} [!b]
\caption{Summary and comparisons of test methods}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ K{5mm} | K{15mm} | K{15mm} || m{20mm} } %<-----
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\#} & \multicolumn{2}{c||}{Combination} & \multirowthead{2}{Summary} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & A & B &  \\ \hline \hline
    1 & \multirow{2}{=}{\centering 1} & A & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    2 & & B &  \\ \cline{1-4}
    3 & \multirow{8}{=}{\centering 2} & A & Note 1. Note 2. \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4} %<-----
    4 & & B & See \#3 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    5 & & C & Note 1. Note 2 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    6 & & D & Note 1. Note 2. Note 3. Note 4. \\ \cline{1-4}
    7 & \multirow{4}{=}{\centering 2} & A &  \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    8 & & B & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    9 & & C & \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
    10 & & D & \\ \cline{1-4}
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:PWM4legComparison}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```